# Sort dataframe column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has four columns: ID, Extraversion, Neuroticism, Openness [image]

I want to reduce the column to three, so I end up with the following columns: ID, Personality, Scores [image]

Please any helps with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help.